# Pandas incremental values when boolean changes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There is a dataframe that contains column in which boolean values alternate.  I want to create incremental value series based on those boolean changes. I want to increment only when boolean value differs from previous value. I want to do this without loop.

Example, Here's dataframe:

```
   column
0    True
1    True
2   False
3   False
4   False
5    True
```

I want to get this:

```
 column  inc
0    True    1
1    True    1
2   False    2
3   False    2
4   False    2
5    True    3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compare shifted column by not equal and add cumulative sum:

```
df['inc'] = df['column'].ne(df['column'].shift()).cumsum()
print (df)
   column  inc
0    True    1
1    True    1
2   False    2
3   False    2
4   False    2
5    True    3
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['column'].ne(df['column'].shift()))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: column, dtype: bool
```